# How to use the child route in angular for render other view detail

Tags: angular

```js
This is my code in routing module
const routes: Routes = [
 { path:'', component:LoginComponent},
 { path:'home', component:HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  children: [
   { path: 'mecanico', component:AdminComponent,
    children: [
     { path:'create_item', component:NuevoItemComponent},
     { path:'consulta_item', component:ConsultaItemComponent},
     { path:'plan', component:PlanMantenimientoComponent, 
      children:
       [{ path:'formato_general/:id', component:FormatoGeneralComponent}]},     
     { path:'operando', component:EquipoOperandoComponent},
     { path:'detenido', component:EquipoDetenidoComponent},
     { path:'resumen', component:ResumenComponent},
     { path:'ver_planes', component:VerPlanesComponent, 
      children:
       [{ path:'edit_planes/:id', component:EditPlanesComponent}]},     
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
```

```html
In my view this is my code
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover" *ngIf="sizze !=0">
            <thead>
              <th style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="20%">LINEA</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="40%">EQUIPO</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="20%">FECHA SOLICITUD</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="10%">ESTATUS PLAN</th>
              <th style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="10%">ACCIONES</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let planes of plan | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: p }">
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="20%">{{planes.LINEA}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="40%">{{planes.EQUIPO}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="20%">{{planes.FECHA | date:'fullDate'}}</td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="10%" *ngIf="planes.ESTATUS === 1"> 
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success" (click)="changeStatus($event,data.id)" #data id="StatusId{{planes.id_planes}}" value="APROBADO">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;APROBADO&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="10%" *ngIf="planes.ESTATUS === 3"> 
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"  (click)="changeStatus($event,data.id)" #data id="StatusId{{planes.id_planes}}" value="NO APROBADO">NO APROBADO</button>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;font-size: 15px;" width="10%">
                  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-block" [routerLink]="['edit_planes',planes.id_planes]"><i class="far fa-eye"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

actually,  i tried of render other view in my angular project with child routes because i have three types of users and my problem is like show the content other view when the user click on button, the button contains the id from my array
When the user click on the button dont render the other view and stand in the same view but URL change 
my links:
http://localhost:4200/home/mecanico/plan
click on button:
http://localhost:4200/home/mecanico/plan/formato_general/4

```
  my function in subcomponent 

  UpdatePlanData(){   //  Funcion que sirve para obtener los datos del plan de mantenimiento separando el equipo operando y detenido, seleccionado con un id desde la vista
    const plan = this.actRoute.snapshot.params;   //  Se obtiene el id de la url del plan que se haya seleccionado
    if(plan.id){      //  Si esta el argumento id entra
      this.itemServ.updatePlanData(plan.id).subscribe(
        res =>
          {
            this.operando = res[0].operando;
            this.detenido = res[1].detenido;
            this.plan     = res[2].plan;
            this.equipo = this.plan[0].EQUIPO;
            this.fecha =  this.plan[0].FECHA;
            this.lengOp = this.operando.length;   //  Se obtiene la longitud para los controles de paginacion
            this.lengDe = this.detenido.length;   //  Se obtiene la longitud para los controles de paginacion
          },
        err =>
          {
            console.log(err,"error update plan data");
          }
      )}else{
        console.log("El argumento en la URL no es un id valido en edit_planes component");
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what you're asking. What do you mean by `When the user click on the button dont render the other view and stand in the same view but URL change my links`? (There's also a StackOverflow in Spanish, if you want to just ask your question in Spanish: [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to route in the routed pages?
if that this the case

Make each component in a new module then define the internal routes in that module, so whenever you route to the module, you can route in the internal routes.

keep your current routes as they are, and declare new module(import these modules in app.module), and within that module make new components where you want to route in that module.

check this out: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8apbns) Just a sample example for your use.

Here there is one component in app.module and a module called intmodule and there are two components in intmodule. From the app.module we can route between hello.component and intmodule and in intmodule we can route between comp1 and comp2.

comment for more help :)